# How to move the abbreviation list on previous page with heading List of Abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviation

I am writing my thesis in LaTex. The code is given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside, openright]{Thesis}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lmodern,babel,adjustbox,booktabs,multirow}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\newcommand{\n}[2]{\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\input{Outer.tex}
\input{Front.tex}
\input{Rights.tex}


\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certificate}
\include{Certificate/certificate1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\include{Dedication/dedication1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\include{Declaration/declaration1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement}
\include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\include{Abstract/abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\include{Abbreviation/abbreviation}
\clearpage
%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{Chapter1/chapter1}
%\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
%\include{Chapter3/chapter3}
%\include{Chapter4/chapter4}
%\include{Chapter5/chapter5}
%\include{Chapter6/chapter6}
%\include{Chapter7/chapter7}

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\footnotesize
\bibliography{References/references}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publications from the Thesis Work}
\small
\include{Publications/publications}
    
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Brief Biography of the Candidate}
\include{Biography/biography}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Brief Biography of the Supervisor}
\include{Biography/kksir}

\end{document}
```

The output pdf of the page with a list of abbreviations comes in two pages with the previous heading of the list of Tables. Can someone please guide how to make it on the same page? The output page is given as :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou56m.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Va9.jpg)
@Zarko please guide sir